# Informatica- Snowflake JDBC error while fetching details of data loaded in a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a workflow in informatica , which has post-SQL query which is executed on Snowflake (Src:Snowflake, Trgt: Snowflake). The result is very large (3B+ rows), at the end of the post-sql the informatica halts with error 'Number too large to be stored as in at batch index 1 use executeLargeBatch() instead'.

Can anyone please help as to how/where can we implement this function.

Thanks!!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that you are running a query that returns 3 billion records? If not, please provide more details about what the query is (i.e. provide the sql) and what you are expecting it to return

Comment: Hi,
So query is working as expected and inserting 3 billion records.
But when relaying the info back to informatica it is giving error.
I suspect it is related to SNOW-74252 , which was fixed . But rn i have no clue on where to implement the executeLargeBatch() function.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're using ODBC or JDBC? The title mentions ODBC but the JIRA you mentioned (SNOW-74252) if for JDBC connector and the error as well, I can't find it in ODBC.

Comment: It's JDBC error.

Comment: I am not sure how informatica can use jdbc and normally it uses ODBC. Irrespective of that, a post SQL with 3B row need a lot of memory, have you tried splitting row into a optimized chunk? What does post sql do? does load completes and then post sql gets stuck ? This mean post sql has some issue or not able to handle the operation.

Comment: The postsql is working fine as it is loading the data in snowflake, it's just when it is returning the updateCount to informatica it is saying that value is too large to be stored as int.